# Merge a lot of df using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big df and use 'chunksize' to divide it. 
after that that I use loop to go through the interval of df and next loop to do some condition and next I want to merge all of this df. I try 'concat(df)' but it return error. method 'join' is not convenient because I have 400 df. 
how can I concatenate this? 
This code

```
el = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=100000)
buys = pd.read_excel('smartphone.xlsx')
buys['date'] = pd.to_datetime(buys['date'])
dates1 = buys['date']
ids1 = buys['id']
for i in el:
i['used_at'] = pd.to_datetime(i['used_at'])
df = i.sort_values(['ID', 'used_at'])
dates = df['used_at']
ids = df['ID']
urls = df['url']
for i, (id, date, url, id1, date1) in enumerate(zip(ids, dates, urls, ids1, dates1)):
    df1 = df[(df['ID'] == ids1[i]) & (df['used_at'] < (dates1[i] + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=5)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)) & (df['used_at'] > (dates1[i] - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)).replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0))]
    df1 = DataFrame(df1)
    if df1.empty:
        continue
    else:
        df_upd = concat(df1, ignore_index=True)
        book = load_workbook('report_buy2.xlsx')
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('report_buy2.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
        df_upd.to_excel(writer, "Main")

        writer.save()
```

Comment: Please show some code you tried, and post the full error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The pandas v0.18.1 documentation [Merge, join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) states a list of dataframes as argument / parameter to the concat function as sample:

```
import pandas as pd
# ... generate df1 et al.
frames = [df1, df2, df3]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

In the preamble it states "The concat function (in the main pandas namespace) does all of the heavy lifting of performing concatenation operations along an axis while performing optional set logic (union or intersection) of the indexes (if any) on the other axes. Note that I say “if any” because there is only a single possible axis of concatenation for Series."

So in your case, the df chunks being also dataframes should be collected in a container and that container then (above named `frames`) be given to the concat function to return a new dataframe with all chunks concatenated.

If this function also accepts general iterables might be looked up there ...

Comment: problem in that I convert one `df`. I add my code to question